# MathJax Test Page Warning

Tags: javascript, web, latex, mathjax

I download the latest MathJax package, and deploy it in my own website(IIS).

I include the js file in `index.html` file as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/mysite/MathJax/MathJax.js"></script>
```

But things are weird that there's warning like below:

[image]

I change the code, use the online js, like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js"></script>
```

Everything seems ok.

[image]

What confuse me is that I just only change the include file.
I notice that there's a hint when I load the page

```
Web-Fonts not available -- using image fonts instead
```

But I don't know why. So does anyone can tell me what happened?

Comment: Regarding CKEditor tag; is this within a CKEditor editable? Is the TestPage inside CKEditor or ...?

Comment: No CKEditor in my test page.

Comment: Can you provide more information? E.g., a live sample page, your MathJax configuration, your browser and OS versions.

Comment: I download the MathJax-2.4-latest from https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/archive/v2.3-latest.zip

Comment: I use the test file in the zip file.

Comment: Which browser and OS versions? Are you opening local files or accessing via a webserver?

Comment: chrome 41.0 windows7. Accessing via IIS

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the developer console? Do you have all of MathJax installed?

Comment: Does your server serve the fonts with the proper mime types?  You might need to do something like what is documented [here](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/installation.html#cross-domain-linking)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.
This is caused by IIS.
Because the mathJax include a lot of *.woff (Web Open Font Format) file which the IIS doesn't support.

So I add the .woff file in the MIME type of IIS.

```
fileExtension： .woff
mimeType：application/x-font-woff
```

And then, everything is OK.
Thank you!